# Npm Package that can display a JS object visually?

Tags: javascript, object, npm

Does anyone know of a package that can display a js object visually on a page? Similar to what happens chrome/firefox console when inspecting an object.

For example if you run in the following chrome console tab:

```
{"one": 'test', "two": {"awesome": ["sauce", "sauce"]}}
```

You'll get a nice toggleable tree to drill down into the props of an object.

Looked around a bit but couldn't find anything on the webs.

Thanks all!

Comment: Do mean instead of [Object]?  If so, JSON.stringify({"one": 'test', "two": {"awesome": ["sauce", "sauce"]}}) might help?

Comment: Nah this would some sort of npm package to inspect an object visually, through a tree view or something like that.

Comment: Something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/treeify? Or do you want it as an javascript/html interactive for your webpage, and if so what front-end framework are you using? This is available for react: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-tree

Comment: Ahh that is awesome. Really like the react-json-tree. Interesting that its a separate npm, but the same package. Would be nice if they pulled that out for easier contributions, as its super nice.